# Lifetime of class instance passed from one form to another

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My project uses several forms to collect information. Since child forms cannot access variables from the method in which they were instantiated, I decided to create a custom Class that can hold gathered information from the child forms in order to use that information in the parent form. However, I am unsure of when the instance of my custom class will be disposed.

Form1 collects information and uses that to determine which child form to launch next.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim customClass As New CustomClass
        Dim form2 As New Form2(customClass)
        form2.Show()
        Dim form3 As New Form3(customClass)
        form3.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form2 collects data and assigns values to shared variables in CustomClass, as well as making several function calls.

```
Public Class Form2

    Private _CustomClass As CustomClass

    Public Sub New(ByRef instance As CustomClass)
        InitializeComponent()
        _CustomClass = instance
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        _CustomClass.MySharedVariable = TextBox1.Text
        _CustomClass.MyCustomMethod()
        Me.Close()
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

When is `customClass` destroyed? Is it disposed after `End Sub` from its parent method, or is it disposed after all the forms using that instance have closed?

Comment: custom class will never be disposed because you never call CustomClass.Dispose() - it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Rather than forms creating class instances and passing them around, consider making the Class the focal point.  The Employee class creates and uses the form as it needs to.  The next level up would be ORMs where the app has service dedicated layers.

Comment: If you only are using a single instance, maybe a shared class might be what you need. There is only a single set of data but the methods can be called without an instance of the class. ClassName.MethodName(). Your object will disappear when there are no more references to it. The garbage collector will call Finalize if you have provided one and the reclaim the memory. The GC runs when it needs more room on the heap (where objects live) so the actual time of destruction cannot be pinpointed.

Comment: In your example it will go cease to be accessible and be marked for garbage collection when the button_click event handler completes. If you declare it at form level in Form1, it will stay accessible until you either dispose it or the program quits

Comment: Incidentally, classes are already reference types, so I suspect you don't actually need to specify `ByRef`. I may be wrong.